# Group the indexes of the same elements in a array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

There is a `int[]` array that stores different numbers.

What I want is **to group the indexes of those same numbers in the array to the same groups.**

For exmaple, the array is `int[5]{1,2,5,1,5}`

I would like to see the output is `List<List<int>> { {0,3}, {1}, {2,4} } // don't mind syntax`

It's better if Linq (or a more efficient way) can be used, thanks for help.

Comment: May you explain how you get this output?

Comment: What results would you expect for the input of `{1,1,1,2,2,3,4,3,5}`? _This feels like a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?_

Comment: the output stores index of the elements grouped together

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `GroupBy` and the position obtained from the `Select` overload:

```
int[] array;

var result = array.Select((v, idx) => new { Value = v, Index = idx })
                  .GroupBy(g => g.Value)
                  .Select(g => g.ToArray()) // inner array
                  .ToArray(); // outer array
```

Answer (score 0):

One of ways:

```
var result = myArray.Select((elem, idx) => new { Value = elem, Idx = idx})
                    .GroupBy(proxy => proxy.Value);

foreach (var grouped in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Element {0} has indexes: {1}", 
                 grouped.Key, 
                 string.Join(", ", grouped.Select(proxy => proxy.Idx).ToArray()));
}

var myFinalList = result.Select(proxy => proxy.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.Range` combined with `GroupBy`:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 5, 1, 5 };

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length)
            .GroupBy(i => arr[i])
            .Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9b6xZl)